# Как объявить entity в одном месте (Android)

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!Никогда раньше не писал на java/C. 
Приведу пример кода:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   
public static int num,count;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    num=0;
    count=0;
}

public void MyOnClickAction(View view) 
{
    Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    TextView firsttextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firsttextwiew);
    num++;
    if (num > 10) {
        sendButton.setText(String.valueOf(num));
        firsttextview.setText("Button pressed " + String.valueOf(num) + " times. Wow!");
    }
    else {firsttextview.setText("Button pressed " + String.valueOf(num) + " times");
        sendButton.setText(String.valueOf(num));
    }
    }
public void ClearCounter(View view) 
{
    Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    TextView firsttextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firsttextwiew);
    TextView countshow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countshow);
    if (num > 0) {
    num=0;
    sendButton.setText(String.valueOf(num));
    firsttextview.setText("Button pressed " + String.valueOf(num) + " times");
    count++;
    countshow.setText("Count of count clears: " + String.valueOf(count));
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Нулевой счетчик!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Как мне объявить вот это:

```
Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
```

В одном месте, а не в разных (Кстати, как они Называются -классы или функции?) классах.
Чтобы потом из любого другого места кода обращаться просто по sendButton.
Пробовал добавить в OnCreate- не получилось. Компилятор их не увидел.!

[image: скрин]

Comment: Этот код написан в процессе изучения java и никакой функциональной нагрузки не несёт. Кстати, как мне в MainActivity обратиться к string.xml? Чтобы вставить значение из @string в, например, setText

Comment: `textView.setText(getString(R.string.NAME_OF_STRING_IN_XML));` или просто `textView.setText(R.string.NAME_OF_STRING_IN_XML);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляйте как поле класса и объявляйте в onCreate():

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {   
        private Button sendButton;
        ...
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
            ...
         }
         ...
    }
```

Comment: Пробовал. Получаю "Unknown field or variable sendButton. Ругается на ту часть, Которая слева от " равно"

Comment: А дальше, соответственно, unknown entity sendButton

Comment: Добавил в топик скрин с ошибкой

Comment: @AlexandrBlinov, вы на уровне класса переменную не объявили. См. вторую строку кода сего ответа.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , VAndrJ Спасибо! Действительно помогло. Подскажите попутно, как называется секция внутри класса MainActivity "Protected void onCreate..."{ } ?

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо!  Нашёл книгу "Google Android: создание приложений для смартфонов и планшетных Пк". Думаю, для изучения подойдёт, т.к. Первая пара глав достаточно понятно расписана.